# Spring boot: multiple bean method which return same datatype across different Service classes

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

These two are Service classes, which makes http calls to other services to retreive the json response. Just wanted to know if this is a proper way to use ResourceConverter which helps to convert json response string to POJO.

bIf you notice, these two seperate classes contains its own `ResourceConverter` Bean method. I cant create a single method which can be shared by all classes, because we need `DummyResponse.class` and `TestResponse.class` as the parameter. So, Is this way acceptable? Is it good practise to have multiple bean methods which return the same type, but in different classes?

```
@Service
 public class TestClient(){

   @Bean
   private ResourceConverter getTestResponseConverter(){
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.setDeserialization(DeserializationFeature.ALLOW_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
      ResourceConverter converter = new ResourceConverter(mapper,TestResponse.class);
      return converter;
   }

   private TestResponse getTestResponse(){
       //okhttp call to get the json, this is not actual syntax for call, not relevant in this context
       String responseBodyString = okhttp.call(request);
       JSONAPIDocument<TestResponse> testDocument = getTestResponseConverter().readDocument(responseBodyString, TestResponse.class);
       return testDocument.get();
   }

}



@Service
public class DummyClient(){

   @Bean
   private ResourceConverter getDummyResponseConverter(){
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.setDeserialization(DeserializationFeature.ALLOW_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
      ResourceConverter converter = new ResourceConverter(mapper,DummyResponse.class);
      return converter;
   }

   private Dummy getDummyResponse(){
       //okhttp call to get the json, this is not actual syntax for call, not relevant in this context
       String responseBodyString = okhttp.call(request);
       JSONAPIDocument<DummyResponse> dummyDocument = getDummyResponseConverter().readDocument(responseBodyString, DummyResponse.class);
       return testDocument.get();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should/can use `@Primary` to annotate the one that will take precedence if there is an `@Autowired ResourceConverter...` and Spring can't tell the difference.

You can use `@Qualifier` to "name" each one and then the same annotation on the `@Autowire`d bean to get the one you want.

So:

```
@Bean
private ResourceConverter testResponseConverter(){
...
}
```

and

```
@Bean
@Primary
private ResourceConverter dummyResponseConverter(){
...
}
```

You can do:

```
@Autowired ResourceConverter rc; // Gets the @Primary dummy one
@Autowired @Qualifier("testResponseConverter") ResourceConverter rc2; // Gets the corresponding testResponseConverter
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html